# Missing QLayout constructor to implement Card Layout

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to implement this CardLayout example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html but when i try to compile the given file card.h, it fails complaining about the constructor of QLayout since there are no overloads accepting the given parameters.

Did i miss something about this example? Is this example only available for an older version of Qt? I'm using Qt 5.12

Card.h code

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QList>

class CardLayout : public QLayout
{
public:
    CardLayout(QWidget *parent, int dist): QLayout(parent, 0, dist) {}
    CardLayout(QLayout *parent, int dist): QLayout(parent, dist) {}
    CardLayout(int dist): QLayout(dist) {}

private:
    QList<QLayoutItem*> list;
};
#endif
```

Comment: which of all the constructors is complaining?

Comment: all of them are missing

Comment: yes, see my answer and the official doc

Answer (score 0):

well according to the doc of qt 5.12

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html

there is no such constructos fot the QLayout class anymore,

you have only

```
QLayout(QWidget *parent)
```

and

```
QLayout()
```

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that. I'm not sure why this example use those constructors even on the 5.12 documentation